# C# Keyboard hooks, keys up event

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, hook, keyboard-hook

I have a C# function that I'm trying to figure out, here is the code :

```
private int KbHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            var hookStruct = (KbLLHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KbLLHookStruct));

            bool ctrlDown = GetKeyState(0xA2) != 0 || GetKeyState(0xA3) != 0;

            if (hookStruct.vkCode == 0x56 && hookStruct.KF_REPEAT == 0)
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(" ");
                MessageBox.Show("Hit ?);
            }                
        }

        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Message : KEY UP");
        }

        // Pass to other keyboard handlers. Makes the Ctrl+V pass through.
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);        
    }
```

so what I'm looking for here is to figure out how to fire the event when the L_CTRL + V button are pressed. It is working; however I only want the event to fire after the keys are up, and for that I am lost. Can anyone offer any direction?

Answer (score 0):

> I only want the event to fire after the keys are up, and for that I am lost. Can anyone offer any direction?

If you only want to respond when the keys are released, then only respond to the [`WM_KEYUP` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281.aspx).

Remove the portion of your `if` statement that handles the `WM_KEYDOWN` message.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Cody Gray, however i only want the event to fire if the user has pressed both the "Ctrl + V" how would i structure that statement for the WM_KEYUP ? cus the nested if statemnt that checks to see if the ctrl btn is down will (at that point) see it as up ... its a catch 22 :( i think i need a listner of some kind..

Comment: Also I get an letup event for both the Ctrl and the V keys and I only want one event.

Comment: @Canada_Goose: I don't know what you mean a listener. A hook *is* a listener. What you will need to do is set a flag (boolean variable declared at the class level) when the Ctrl key is pressed down (`WM_KEYDOWN`), and then check that flag when you receive notification that the V key was released (`WM_KEYUP`). If the flag is true, then the user had pressed Ctrl+V. If the flag is false, then they just pressed V, so you do nothing. Either way, reset the flag to false when you get notification that the Ctrl key was released (`WM_KEYUP`).

Comment: That's great news, do you think you could show me a snippet of how that would function ? Thanks again for your responses your very helpful !

Comment: Hard to show you a snippet while typing this on a phone... :-) Honestly, I've wrapped all that code up into a component that I use when I need to hook from C#. You might consider doing the same, or better yet, downloading a complete hook library, like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET).

Comment: Ahhh, ok I have seen this libary already buy I fuiger that I would try to learn before I hijacked someone else's lib. I'll hold out for an example of your awnser if u can get the time cuz I have a hard time leaning C# so I will get confused if I change everything now.

Comment: is there anyone else that can offer a snippet of code that will do what @cody_Grey said to try ? I'm not sure how i would set the flag at the class level ....

Comment: @Canada: You don't know how to declare and set a class-level variable? I don't mean this to sound rude, but I'm not really sure that you need to be writing a hook... This is slightly more advanced programming, and you should be sure that you have the basics down first. If you just need to make an app work, you definitely need to use one of the existing hooking libraries. I suppose I could post *my* code that you could just drop into an existing project, but it's in VB.NET. One of us would have to convert it to C#.

Comment: @Canada: Also, I can't believe I forgot to ask this already. What problem are you actually trying to solve? That is, why do you need to install a low-level hook? Is your application supposed to respond **system-wide** to a `Ctrl+L` key press? I really don't recommend that; lots of apps do things when you press `Ctrl+L`, and users should be able to use those *other* apps without yours doing something unexpected. It's quite rare that global hooks are even necessary. You certainly don't need them to use keyboard shortcuts in your own app. And globally, something like `RegisterHotKey` might work.